# How can I extract element from Set with zero or one element in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, set

**Problem:**

Let's say we have a `Set`  of `a` with zero or one element.
And we need to get this element if it exists.

I have searched for function `Set a -> Maybe a` on hoogle and I found the following functions:

`lookupMin :: Set a -> Maybe a`

and

`lookupMax :: Set a -> Maybe a`

**Question:**

What is the idiomatic way to get `a` in this case?

Should I use pattern matching or one of these functions?

Comment: `head :: (Foldable f) => f a -> Maybe a` is the clear idiomatic choice.

Comment: What do you find unidiomatic about `lookupMin`?

Comment: Both `lookupMin` and `lookupMax` look fine to me, under your hypotheses. You can't pattern match on a `Set` (it's an opaque type), so using some function is in order.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner I am just looking for the right way to do it, both functions are legitimate in this case.

Comment: What lets you assume the set has at most one element? Maybe `Set a` is the wrong type to be using in the first place.

Comment: There has been talk of adding `NonEmptySet` to the "containers" library. For that type, `lookupMin` and `lookupMax` would be total https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2019-April/029537.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move some of the comments into an answer and add my own 2¢:

I find both `lookupMin` and `lookupMax` unidiomatic, because they say to me as a reader "get me the min/max element (if any) from the set", whereas our intention is more "get me an arbitrary element (if any) from the set". This intention-reading is fundamentally complicated by the fact that a `Set` isn't really the right type of 0-or-1-`a`s, indeed that's a `Maybe`.

AJFarmer suggests `head :: (Foldable f) => f a -> Maybe a` which I agree is a good name & type, but it's from an alternative prelude (protolude). You can easily implement it yourself, `listToMaybe . toList` is all from base libraries, though then you'll have to find a name for it.

Lenses provide another solution, `(^? _Wrapped . _head)`.

If our intention reads better as "check if it's a singleton, and if so, extract the element" then we can maybe do better, though.

```
fromSingleton :: Set a -> Maybe a
fromSingleton s = case toList s of
    [a] -> Just a
    _ -> Nothing
```

Or perhaps,

```
fromSingleton :: Set a -> Maybe a
fromSingleton (toList -> [x]) = Just x
fromSingleton _ = Nothing
```

As chi says, you can't pattern-match on `Set`, but if you wanted to you could set up pattern synonyms to do so eg.

```
pattern Empty <- (Set.toList -> [])
pattern Singleton x <- (Set.toList -> [x])
pattern Many xs <- (Set.toList -> xs@(_:_:_))

fromSingleton :: Set a -> Maybe a
fromSingleton (Singleton x) = Just x
fromSingleton _ = Nothing
```

This is probably overkill if all you need is the one function though.